# Module not found with readDirSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, node.js-fs

### SOLVED

I get a `Cannot find module` error once the readDirSync Function (`npm i fs`) runs on a module I imported before that and is in a different Dir than the readDirSync Function reads.

main.js

```js
const { log, clear } = require("console");
clear();

const fs = require("fs");

const time = require("./test.js");
const { genArr, findHighest } = require("./Util.js");

const sortingAlgos = {};
fs.readdirSync("./sort/")
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
    .forEach((file) => {
        sortingAlgos[file] = require(`./sort/${file}`);
    });

log(sortingAlgos);

const arr = genArr(100000, 10000);

time(native, arr, "native");
time(rawBastSort, arr, "rawBS");
time(bubbleSort, arr, "bubble");
```

The code is first supposed to import all Functions from `Utils.js` and then import all files inside the `sort` folder.

Code runs and imports fine without the `readdirSync`.

Debugger shows the code broken at the `readdirSync` call.

Same Error if I comment out the first import of Util.js (ln. 7)

File Structure

```
| main.js
| package-lock.json
| package.json
| test.js
| Util.js
|
| sort
   |- bastSort.js
   |- bubbleSort.js
   |- native.js
   \- rawBastSort.js
```

Error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './Util.js'
Require stack:
- E:\Computer\Code\Javascript\Coding\Testen und Shit\Bast Sort\sort\bastSort.js
- E:\Computer\Code\Javascript\Coding\Testen und Shit\Bast Sort\main.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Computer\Code\Javascript\Coding\Testen und Shit\Bast Sort\sort\bastSort.js:1:33)  
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\Computer\\Code\\Javascript\\Coding\\Testen und 
Shit\\Bast Sort\\sort\\bastSort.js',
    'E:\\Computer\\Code\\Javascript\\Coding\\Testen und 
Shit\\Bast Sort\\main.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: fs is not an npm module, so I'm not sure what `npm i fs` did. Please include the complete text of any errors you've received.

Comment: Does it actually break at readdirSync? Your errors shows `Error: Cannot find module './Util.js'` can you post the contents of Util.js?

Comment: @chrisbyte It breakes at the call of readDirSync (Debugger step by step). if i remove readdirSync it workes and imports ./Utils.js correctly.
(Util.js exports 2 functions in an object)

Comment: Does the "bastSort.js" file import Util.js?

Comment: @GeriDremák yes it does, and i misspelled the path and solved it now thx

Comment: i misspelled the path and solved it now thx